# Jobs custom profile link

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

After I set custom profile URL for my jobs profile I'm getting error page:

> We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred
>   while you were browsing our site.
>
> It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.

Everything else seems to be working fine. Is it a temporary server problem or it's a bug and needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your profile appears to be private. It should be redirecting to a 404 but it's currently an error page. We're working on fixing that.

In the meantime navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/cv and make your profile public by using the 'Settings' button in the sidebar.

[image: Settings]

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my profile was private. But when I as owner click on it, should be displayed info something like "hey, your profile is private, make it public to allow other users to see it" or something like this

Comment: It works like that intentionally; you see what other users will see. That way it's obvious that the CV is actually private. At least it would be if it returned a 404. We can modify that to show a 'Make this public' page or similar. I'll add to the backlog!

Comment: Probably you are right but I was creating my job profile today and haven't noticed private flag and if you haven't told me that I would be probably thinking it's a bug. Maybe information that job profile is private should be displayed when you go in jobs page?

Comment: Yup, added to the backlog. Thanks for the feedback!